# Make UIAlertController accessibilityLabel different from title

Tags: ios, accessibility, uialertcontroller

I'm hinting some strings in my app for VoiceOver. I'm expanding some abbreviations, like "opp" → "opposite" and "ave" → "avenue", so that VoiceOver pronounces them correctly. However, I want to use one of these strings as the title of a UIAlertController (iOS 9+). I want to set the `title` to the unmodified string, but the `accessibilityLabel` to the pronounceable string. Is this possible without traversing the subviews, which is fragile so I'd rather avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is not possible. I've [filed a radar](http://www.openradar.me/27286870).

Answer (score 0):

Although this approach doesn't satisfy the OP's desire to avoid traversing the subviews it may be useful to someone:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let titleText = NSLocalizedString("File eBill", comment: "File eBill Header Title")
        let userMessage = NSLocalizedString("The eBill could not be filed.", comment: "File eBill Error")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleText, message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert )

        if let titleLabel = alert.view.firstLabel(with: titleText) {
            let pronunciationTitle = NSLocalizedString("File e-Bill", comment: "File eBill pronunciation")
            titleLabel.accessibilityLabel = pronunciationTitle
        }
        if let messageLabel = alert.view.firstLabel(with: userMessage) {
            let pronunciationMessage = NSLocalizedString("The e-Bill could not be filed.", comment: "File eBill error pronunciation")
            messageLabel.accessibilityLabel = pronunciationMessage
        }

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            print("Done")
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension UIView {

    /// Returns a UILabel that matches the text input if such exists within the view.
    /// Probes recursively and exhaustively.
    func firstLabel(with text: String) -> UILabel? {
        var result: UILabel?
        for view in subviews {
            if let label: UILabel = view as? UILabel,
               label.text == text {
                result = label
                break
            } else {
                if let deeper = view.firstLabel(with: text) {
                    result = deeper
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```